# Getting exception after login of Integrated facebook in two screen

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-login

I Integrate Facebook login in my android app in **two screen**

> 1. LoginScreen
> 2. SignupScreen

If I'm open only one screen and do login with facebook then it will successfully login, but when I open both screen one by one and do login with any of the screen then exception occurs (After user's profile data get).

> For e.g.
>
> Scenario 1 : If I'm open LoginScreen then Open SignupScreen then
>   backPress. Now I'm in LoginScreen again. Now I'm doing login with
>   facebook the **Exception is occure.**
>
> Scenario 2 :  Open LoginScreen > Open SignupScreen > Now login with facebook 
>   in SignupScreen the **exception occur.**
>
> Scenario 3 : Open LoginScreen only then do Login with facebook. ***No
>   Exception occur***

Exception :

```
11-14 10:39:08.821 32571-32571/com.mypackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: com.mypackage, PID: 32571
                                                       android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@1f092e9 is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:579)
                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
                                                           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                           at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                                                           at com.mypackage.SignUp.SignUpActivity.sendSocialIdRequest(SignUpActivity.java:697)
                                                           at com.mypackage.SignUp.SignUpActivity.access$400(SignUpActivity.java:65)
                                                           at com.mypackage.SignUp.SignUpActivity$8.onCompleted(SignUpActivity.java:670)
                                                           at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304)
                                                           at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1368)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Can u post how u r trying to open an alert Dialog or progress dialog in SignUpActivity?

Comment: for Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 add fb login code on login screen not on SignupScreen.

Comment: I added FB login code in both screen.

Comment: just add in login screen and pass data SignupScreen screen

Comment: Both screen have a different sign in button for facebook. That's why I need to put code in both screen.